# Magento 2 optimization - loading time is high

Tags: magento2, redis, optimization

High configuration server with Redis configuration.

Gtmatrix - https://gtmetrix.com/reports/mastersdirect.masters-sp.com/UQcit4p9

Waiting time is 2.68 s.

Created a normal controller and exit in the index file of the module but this is taking 3s to load and total page load time is higher than 20sec.

Website controller url  - http://mastersdirect.masters-sp.com/shop/stockmanagement

Total loading time is 30 s - http://mastersdirect.masters-sp.com/shop/customer/account/login/

Comment: what is your question? I checked and my load times for your customer/account page: 
Finish: 8.67 s
DOMContentLoaded: 6.95 s
Load: 7.63 s

Also I see the output of what it looks as a profile, this could also add loading time to your page

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the server has at least 2GB of RAM